# Procedure Method, text surrounded

Tags: java

```
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        String r;
        int w;
        int h;
        char c;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the text: ");
        r=sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter the character : ");
        c = sc.next().charAt(0);
        System.out.println("Enter your width: ");
        w=sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter your height: ");
        h=sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println();
        textbox(c,r,w,h);
    }

    public static void textbox (char c, String r, int w, int h)
    {
        String middle = c + "  " + r + "  " + c;
        for (int i = 0; i < h; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < w; j++) {
                if (i == 0 || i == h-2) {
                    System.out.print(c);
                } else if (j ==w-1) {
                    System.out.print(middle);
                } 
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

I have to make the program use a method that accepts a string and prints the string centered horizontally on the screen surrounded by a box six characters longer than the message. 
Limit the length of the string to ensure it will fit on the screen. It doesn't do what I want it to do, the rows don't match and it displays the word more than once(depending on  the height).

Comment: can you post your expected output?

Comment: @SagarPudi, can i give u an example

Comment: yeah sure that's what I asked

Comment: First off, don't use variable names like "r,c,h,w". This type of naming doesn't tell anyone what they are. Instead call the text "tx", and character - something like "ch"....

Comment: It is asking credentilals.just post your input and expected output along with your question.

Comment: @SagarPudi, is there a way i can send u pdf file, cuz idk how i am goanna output the box

Comment: *"ok sorry about that"* - He is not asking for an apology.  He is instructing you in how to write good code.  He wants / we want is that you should *learn* the lesson that it is important to use *informative* variable names in your code.  Always.  (Or at least in any code that a human being *might* need to read at some point.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will help you..

Change this code as per your requirement :)

```
   import java.util.Scanner;

    public class TextBox {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String inputString;
            char character;
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter the text: ");
            inputString=sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter the character : ");
            character = sc.next().charAt(0);
            sc.close();
            drawTextbox(character,inputString);
        }
        public static void drawTextbox (char character, String inputString){
            int width=inputString.length()+6;
            for(int i=0;i<width;i++){
                System.out.print(character);    
            }
            System.out.println();
            for(int i=0;i<width;i++){

                if(i==0||i==width-1){
                    System.out.print(character);
                }
                else if(i>2&&i<width-3){
                    System.out.print(inputString.charAt(i-3));
                }else{
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
            for(int i=0;i<width;i++){
                System.out.print(character);

            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: isn't it supposed to be 6 spaces to the left and six to the right? or i am i just misunderstanding the question

Comment: Also, am i supposed to let the user input width/height or no

Comment: also isn't the width supposed to be 13 not twelve? or does it depend on the string

Answer (score 0):

Modified code. Your original code wasn't efficient (for loops - take longer), and this is much simpler. Explanation is in cooments:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String ttc; // ttc - short for text to center.
    char ch;

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the text to center: ");
    ttc=sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter the border character : ");
    ch = sc.next().charAt(0);
    System.out.println();
    textbox(ttc,ch);
}

public static void textbox (String ttc, char ch)
{
    // Size of word to center in middle.
    int textSize = ttc.length();
    // Total width of box is word size plus 12 plus 2 for border.
    int width = textSize + 14;

    // This is the top and bottom of the box. Uses a char array the
    // size of the width the box and replaces null values (\0) with
    // the character specified for the border.
    String topBottom = new String(new char[width]).replace('\0', ch);
    String middle = ch + "      " + ttc + "      " + ch;

    // Print out box.
    System.out.println(topBottom);
    System.out.println(middle);
    System.out.println(topBottom);
}
```

Comment: Alvin Bunk, for the word there has to be 6 spaces to the left and six spaces to the right, plus for the right column, the characters don't match?

Comment: Is there a way u can do that?

Comment: and why are u doing h-1, when u did h/2

Comment: hold a sec - there's an easier way.

Comment: The above modified code meets your requirements and is simpler too.